# HTTP Error 411, The request must be chunked or have a content length

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to login to a remote website but getting error on below code "HTTP Error 411, The request must be chunked or have a content length."

```
$username = "psker";
$password = "Admin123";
$url="https://192.18.11.33/Login.aspx?FromMasterLogin=true"; 
$postinfo = 'txtUserName='.$username.'&txtpassword='.$password.'&txtUserName_ClientState={"enabled":true,"emptyMessage":""}&txtpassword_ClientState={"enabled":true,"emptyMessage":""}&btnLogin_ClientState&btnClearSession_ClientState&rdwindowForget_ClientState&rdwindowEnforce_ClientState&rdWindowPublicNewsAlerts_ClientState&RadWindowManager1_ClientState';
$cookie_file_path = "/cookies.txt";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$headers = array( 
            "Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
            "Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br",
            "Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8",
            "Cache-Control:max-age=0",
            "Connection:keep-alive",
            "Content-Length:1025",
            "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postinfo);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://192.18.11.33/RGCS/Default.aspx?dd=0");
$html = curl_exec($ch);
echo $html;
curl_close($ch);
```

Below are the original headers of login page :

```
Request URL:https://192.18.11.33/Login.aspx?FromMasterLogin=true
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
Remote Address:192.18.11.33:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:34153
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Sat, 15 Apr 2017 09:37:35 GMT
Location:/RGCS/Default.aspx?dd=0
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Set-Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=spw3wky1bsdz0mrwzzojg504; path=/; HttpOnly
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
Request Headers
view source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1025
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=
DNT:1
Host:192.18.11.33
Origin:https://192.18.11.33
Referer:https://192.18.11.33/Login.aspx?FromMasterLogin=true
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
Query String Parameters
view source
view URL encoded
FromMasterLogin:true
Form Data
view source
view URL encoded
__EVENTTARGET:btnLogin
__EVENTARGUMENT:
__VIEWSTATE:/wEPDwULLTEzNDc1MTg5NDRkGAIFHl9fQ29udHJvbHNSZXF1aXJlUG9zdEJhY2tLZXlfXxYGBQhidG5Mb2dpbgUPYnRuQ2xlYXJTZXNzaW9uBRFSYWRXaW5kb3dNYW5hZ2VyMQUOcmR3aW5kb3dGb3JnZXQFD3Jkd2luZG93RW5mb3JjZQUYcmRXaW5kb3dQdWJsaWNOZXdzQWxlcnRzBQpyYWRDYXB0Y2hhDxQrAAIFJDcxZmM0ZThmLTRlYTktNDE2Mi1hZTM4LWE0ZmNkNzM0NzY3ZgYAAAAAAAAAAGTJGSQTauu1xAgiX10rd7/Zci9sJhXV9Ilqy4HDolIBqg==
__EVENTVALIDATION:/wEdAAci11URbCuVmlO2wf1gC0M7Y3plgk0YBAefRz3MyBlTcJxpWckI3qdmfEJVCu2f5cGinihG6d/Xh3PZm3b5AoMQf2Dr69OxAarGhVFbQWZWFpd+ecw9lQ5sg8SY03yGmgNKhPS/+yQ5+zLwEb8uDfAwho9uEQI2joMICVOBiz0yDgel4nUaIRbrrP5r1YBnzqE=
txtUserName:psibmaker
txtUserName_ClientState:{"enabled":true,"emptyMessage":""}
txtpassword:Admin!@123
txtpassword_ClientState:{"enabled":true,"emptyMessage":""}
btnLogin_ClientState:
btnClearSession_ClientState:
rdwindowForget_ClientState:
rdwindowEnforce_ClientState:
rdWindowPublicNewsAlerts_ClientState:
RadWindowManager1_ClientState:
```

So my problem is "The request must be chunked or have a content length."

Can anybody help me? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 17):

The server will not accept requests without a Content-Length header. I see you specified it in your headers as 1025. This length should be the number of bytes after the headers, the body itself. Is 1025 correct, as you have it hardcoded? The existence of a content-length header, indicates the presence of a message body (and the exact (octet) byte length of it, or the connection will close after this amount)

According to https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

> "The Content-Length entity-header field indicates the size of the
>   entity-body, in decimal number of OCTETs, sent to the recipient or, in
>   the case of the HEAD method, the size of the entity-body that would
>   have been sent had the request been a GET"

I also notice you are using ""Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"" in which case consider that the content length must be the length of the url encoded form/whatever data.

I hope this helps!

Comment: ... and specify content length as 0 if no body is sent